# Creating a Cloud Service in Windows Azure gives the error The Specified URL is already in use

Tags: azure, cloud

I am attempting to create a new cloud service on https://manage.windowsazure.com.

No matter what url I enter, I get the same error saying "The Specified URL is already in use"

[image]

It doesn't matter what I type in the URL box, it ALWAYS tells me that the URL is already in use.  I have a hard time believing that this specific URL has already been used.

I've searched for an hour trying to find out why this is happening with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a shorter url? Might be the error msg that is wrong

Comment: Yes, I have.  I just started adding numbers to the end to make sure.

Comment: i just confirmed the same behavior. But mytestwebsite is free.

Comment: I think you just have to accept that it is taken by some one. Not sure what triggered it to be taken.

Comment: Ok, it appears to have something to do with using the keyword "online" in the url.  mytestwebsiteonlin works fine.  As soon as I add in the e to make it mytestwebsiteonline, it fails.  If I change it to mytestonlinwebsite, it works.  mytestonlinewebsite fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the word "**`online`**" from your cloud service name. Your cloud service name can't contain some specific words/phrases and I believe "online" is one of them. I really don't know the reason as to why "**online**" is one of the phrases which is not allowed by Windows Azure. Here's the actual error (I tried creating the same through Azure Management Studio)

[image]

Comment: It appears that MS has flagged "Online" as a phishing term.  Why?  I don't know...  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/bf567147-3921-41e6-baf4-c3b89f77705a/